# Convexity of expected value

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to understand if the expected value of a variable is convex in that variable or not.
I know that expectation is a linear operator, so must be convex.
But I do not see why it does not depend on what characteristics the probability vector $p(x)$ has.
In other words, why $E(x)= x^Tp(x)$ is convex for any $p(.)$ such that $p\ge0, p(x)^T1=1$? Is $p$ constant wrt $x$?
Confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value does not depend on $x$ as we integrate out $x$. So, your question is not meaningful.

Comment: Oh, I see. I should study it as a function of $p$. Sorry about that.